# How to replace characters between flags in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a char variable in Matlab like this:

```
x = 'hello my name $ is Sean $ Daley.';
```

I want to replace the first '$' with the symbol '&', and the second '$' with the symbol '#'.

Furthermore, if I have a more complicated char such that pairs of '$' repeat many times, I want to repeat the same pattern. So the following:

```
y = 'hello $ my $ name is $ Sean $ Daley $.$.';
```

would be transformed into:

```
'hello & my # name is & Sean # Daley &.#.'
```

I have tried coding this manually via for loops and while loops, but the code is just so ugly. Are there any simple functions that I can use?

Comment: `strfind` `strrep` and all of the other `str` type functions are the first thing that pop when you google "replace characters string matlab". Any reason those are not what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're dealing with single characters and non-nested pairs of flags, you can easily do this with a simple call to [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and some [indexed replacement](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html):

```
y = 'hello $ my $ name is $ Sean $ Daley $.$.';
index = find(y == '$');
y(index(1:2:end)) = '&';
y(index(2:2:end)) = '#';
```

And the result:

```
y =

    'hello & my # name is & Sean # Daley &.#.'
```

Comment: Perfect. I'm wondering if there's a simple way to deal with non-single characters? For example, replacing '#$ test #$' with '@@@@ test @@@@'?

Comment: @SeanDaley: That example could be handled with [`strrep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html): `y = strrep(y, '#$', '@@@@');`